# Access values from Matrix in OpenCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, matrix, pixel

For example, I have a matrix M of size 10x10 and I have a column matrix ind of length 5
How can I assign A(ind,:) to a new matrix B in C++ with OpenCV?

Below is how I do in Matlab:

```
A = [ 41     8    33    36    22    14    38    43    18     4
    46    49     2     2    20    34    13    13    42     3
     7    48    43    14    39    33    26    41    30    27
    46    25    47     3    40     9    35    13    28    39
    32    41    34     5    10     6    45    47    46    47
     5     8    38    42    25    25    48    18    15     7
    14    22    38    35    23    48    28    10    38    29
    28    46    20    16    33    18     7    13    38    24
    48    40    33    48    36    30     8    31    20     1
    49    48     9     2    38    12    13    24    29    17]

ind = [2; 8; 4; 6; 2]  

B = A(ind, :);

B = [ 46    49     2     2    20    34    13    13    42     3
    28    46    20    16    33    18     7    13    38    24
    46    25    47     3    40     9    35    13    28    39
     5     8    38    42    25    25    48    18    15     7
    46    49     2     2    20    34    13    13    42     3]
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this in C++ with OpenCV without using for loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct way to extract a random ordering of rows/columns without iterating in some way. The simplest method is to extract rows and push them into the target matrix one by one. Given you have your matrix A declared and its data set:

```
cv::Mat B;
B.push_back(A(cv::Range(2,3),cv::Range::all()));
B.push_back(A(cv::Range(8,9),cv::Range::all()));
B.push_back(A(cv::Range(4,5),cv::Range::all()));
B.push_back(A(cv::Range(6,7),cv::Range::all()));
B.push_back(A(cv::Range(2,3),cv::Range::all()));
```

should do what you want. This uses the overloaded `operator()(cv::rowRange, cv::colRange)` to extract the selected rows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible without using `for` loop but the fastest way of doing this is by using `memcpy`. You can see the complete code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30984292/1040597)