# Fastest way to copy some rows from one matrix to another in OpenCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, matrix

I have a [32678 x 10] matrix (`w2c`) and I want to copy 24700 rows of it to another matrix(`out`). I have the index of the rows to be copied in a vector(`index`). For doing this in matlab I do:

```
out = w2c(index_im,:);
```

It takes approximately 0.002622 seconds.

In OpenCV:

```
Mat out(index.cols, w2c.cols, w2c.type());
for (int i = 0; i < index.cols; ++i) {
    w2c.row(index.at<int>(i) - 1).copyTo(out.row(i));
}
```

It takes approximately 0.015121 seconds.

As you can see Matlab is 6 times faster. How can I make the OpenCV code efficient?

I am using cmake-2.9, g++-4.8, opencv-2.4.9, ubuntu 14.04

**UPDATE**:

I ran my code in release mode, here is the result ( It is still significantly slower than Matlab )

```
RELEASE     DEBUG       MATLAB
0.008183    0.010070    0.001604    
0.009630    0.010050    0.001679
0.009120    0.009890    0.001566
0.007534    0.009567    0.001635
0.007886    0.009886    0.001840
```

Comment: how does the content of the `index` vector look like? is it one or multiple contiguous sections? please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your OpenCV code.

Comment: `index` vector is a matrix with one row and 24700 columns and it is continuous.

Comment: continuous in what way? does it store the values e.g. 0 to 24699? what does it contain?

Comment: it is continuous as `index.isContinious()`. It contains random numbers between 0 and 32677 and it doesn't have any particular order.

Comment: add more details: which OpenCV version, which compiler, which compiler flags, which operating system, and the complete example code

Comment: I don't know about compiler flags and about complete code I have to say this is it. just initialize `w2c` (double) and `index` (int) with random data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81057/discussion-between-m-s-and-sudomakeinstall2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried different methods for this problem and the only way I could achieve a better performance than Matlab was using `memcpy` and directly copying the data myself.

```
    Mat out( index.cols, w2c.cols, w2c.type() );
    for ( int i=0;i<index.cols;++i ){
        int ind = index.at<int>(i)-1;
        const float *src = w2c.ptr<float> (ind);
        float *des = out.ptr<float> (i);
        memcpy(des,src,w2c.cols*sizeof(float));
    }
```

this way the whole thing took approximately 0.001063 that is a little bit faster than Matlab.

Also I found out that copying data this way:

```
    Mat out;
    Mat out( index.cols, w2c.cols, w2c.type() );
    for ( int i=0;i<index.cols;++i ){
        int ind = index.at<int>(i)-1;
        out.push_back(w2c.row(ind)); 
    }
```

is faster than copying it like this:

```
    Mat out( index.cols, w2c.cols, w2c.type() );
    for ( int i=0;i<index.cols;++i ){
        int ind = index.at<int>(i)-1;
        w2c.row(ind).copyTo(out.row(i));
    }
```

but I don't why. Anyway both of them are slower than Matlab.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [our discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81057/discussion-between-m-s-and-sudomakeinstall2) you are not compiling with optimization enabled. If you do this, you will see a notable performance increase. Also, make sure that you are linking against a release build of OpenCV.

I measured the execution time for the following example both without and with optimization enabled:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const int num_rows = 32678;
    const int num_cols = 10;
    const int index_size = 24700;

    const int num_runs = 1000;
    const int seed = 42;

    std::vector<int> index_vec(num_rows);

    // fill index with sequence
    std::iota (index_vec.begin(), index_vec.end(), 0);

    // randomize sequence
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
    g.seed(seed);
    std::shuffle(index_vec.begin(), index_vec.end(), g);

    // trunkate index
    index_vec.resize(index_size);

    cv::Mat w2c(num_rows, num_cols, CV_32F);

    // copy
    cv::Mat out(index_size, w2c.cols, w2c.type());

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int k = 0; k<num_runs; ++k)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < index_size; ++i)
        {
            w2c.row(index_vec[i]).copyTo(out.row(i));
        }
    }

    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start);

    std::cout << duration.count()/num_runs << " microseconds" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(copy)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
add_executable(copy main.cpp)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(copy ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

**Compile and run without optimization**

```
cmake . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG
make
./copy
3924 microseconds
```

**Compile and run with optimization**

```
cmake . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE
make
./copy
2664 microseconds
```

I ran these tests on

- Intel Core i7-4600U CPU
- Ubuntu 14.04 (x64)
- GCC 4.8.2
- OpenCV 3.0.0 (release build)