# OpenCV extract submatrix from certain positions

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

Say I require to extract a submatrix with values on certain positions of another matrix. For example in matlab it work like this:

extract = [1 3 4];
dst = src(extract);

Where src is one dimensional array, extract defines indices of values to extract, and dst is destination array which will keep values on indices 1, 3, 4 of array src.

Is there any way to do the same in Opencv with variable of type cv::Mat assuming that it has only one row? Without looping through every element and just using function.

Comment: If your interval is continuous you can use `Range`s or `Rect`s. Otherwise you need to copy the elements you need (that involves scanning the matrix, but you can wrap it in a function)

Comment: something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30952048/5008845)

Comment: @Miki thank you for quick reply. Yes, Range will not suit as it only takes values within certain range. Seems that I will just have to write function similar to the link you shared and stick with the idea of looping through every element.